# 802.1x wired authentication: How to make NetworkManager ask for identity every time?

Tags: network-manager, security, authentication

I want networkmanager to ask for identity/username every time I connect to the wired network, how can I make this happen?

My current configuration is:

- 802.1x Security: enabled
- Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
- CA certificate: [*my ca cert*]
- PEAP version: automatic
- Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
- Username: [*my username*]
- Password: Ask for this password every time

I configured these options in the system network settings GUI, there is no option to ask for username and I can't leave it blank. When the authentication dialog pops up, I don't have the option to change the username either.

I tried to set an empty value ("") for 802-1x.identity using nmcli, hoping that I could then configure it to ask for username with the --ask option, or that it'd allow me to modify the username in the authentication window:

```
nmcli c modify <UUID> 802-1x.identity ""
```

It fails with error: 802-1x.identity is missing

I also tried

```
nmcli c modify <UUID> -802-1x.identity "anon"
```

the command is successful, but it seems to do nothing.

EDIT: I've created a GUI with just a username textbox that runs nmcli in the background (it's more of a 'proof-of-concept' and not finished). Not sure if it's a good idea, I was hoping there was a 'clean' solution, but for now this might work for me.

```
import wx
from os import system
from shlex import quote

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Authentication", style=wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)

        # Create UI elements
        self.textboxSize = wx.Size(400, -1)
        self.usernameCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=self.textboxSize)
        self.connectButton = wx.Button(self, label="Connect")

        # Create sizer and add UI elements
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label="Username"), 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.usernameCtrl, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        self.sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.connectButton, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.RIGHT, border=5)

        # Register button callback
        self.connectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_connect)
        self.connectButton.SetDefault()

        # Show the frame
        self.sizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

    def on_connect(self, ce):
        self.connectButton.Disable()
        if self.usernameCtrl.GetValue() == "":
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Please enter your username", "Error", wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.CENTRE)
            dlg.ShowModal()
            self.connectButton.Enable()
            return
        system('nmcli c modify "MyNetwork" 802-1x.password-flags 2') # Make sure passwords aren't saved
        system('nmcli c modify "MyNetwork" 802-1x.identity "{}"'.format(quote(self.usernameCtrl.GetValue()))) # Enter the username
        system('nmcli c up "MyNetwork"') # Connect to network and ask for password
        wx.CallAfter(self.Close)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Read https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/NetworkManager.8.html or `man NetworkManager`. You can write a script to  "fix" any network state transition.

Comment: @waltinator That is very interesting and I will look into it. Tbh I don't see how exactly it's going to help me or where to start even, I feel like it'd be easier to make my own GUI to interface with nmcli or something.